# How does the damage resistance on Hush work, and how can you overcome it?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

While trying to get all of my completion marks I have noticed a bit of an issue when it comes to fighting [Hush](https://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Hush) in the Blue Womb. No matter what my build strength, the amount of damage I am able to deal to Hush seems to peter out as I reach the later phases. This is bad for me, as I am not that great at Bullet Hells and having the final phases stretched out ends up with me taking a lot of damage.

Through my research I know that Hush (and Ultra-Greed) are different from normal bosses in BOI in that they have some sort of Armour/Damage Resistance/HP scaling. **I would like to know how that Damage Resistance works specifically to learn strategies to overcome it.**

I know that some item builds like Gnawed Leaf and Pinking Shears/Daddy Long Legs etc. for invincibility and Serpent's Kiss or SharpPlug/Habit and Blankcard/Placebo to heal-up can make taking damage not an issue, but I would rather not be forced to reset until I get those items and the healing builds don't work on The Lost.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/3rzra1/ive_figured_out_ultra_greed_and_the_hushs/), the way it works is that those bosses record how much damage they take and adjust the resistances accordingly.

So if you deal a huge burst of damage all at once, they'll greatly increase the resistance.

Knowing this, the best way to deal with it is either deal bursts of single instanced damage once in a while or attack for a few seconds, stop to let the resistances fall off then attack again.